# Using values from a field in one table as column name for field in another

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables like this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df3e6/10

my wish is to use the name-field from t2 as column name for t3

My end goal is something along the lines of:

```
---------------------------------
| ID | NAME  | AMOUNT | PRODUCT |
---------------------------------
| 1  | name1 |    1   | potato  |
| 2  | name2 |   20   | fruit   |
---------------------------------
```

Is this doable or do I have to "sort" it this way after the query?

Comment: Does your application really need this?

Comment: Probably you should maintain product and amount as two different columns in third table

Comment: @BartFriederichs I have aproxemetly 10 000 lines in t1, 1000 000 in t3 and I would like to do a limit 20 query without having to do 2 seperate queries

Comment: @lampdev in that case I would have to add a new column if I wanted to add more options later on

Comment: An RDMS like MySQL is not very suited for stuff you want to do. You could give a NoSQL database a shot, or rewrite your database schema. Btw, what's wrong with doing two queries? You can wrap them in a view or procedure if you need more functionality.

Comment: @BartFriederichs yeah I know I've been looking at mongodb for a bit but atm that's not doable with the current setup. I guess nothing's "wrong" with having 2 queries I just hoped it was doable in one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pivot* the results based on `name` value.

```
SELECT 
  `t1`.* 
  , max( case when `t2`.`name` = 'amount' then `t3`.`value` 
              else null 
         end ) as 'Amount'
  , max( case when `t2`.`name` = 'product' then `t3`.`value` 
         else null 
         end ) as 'Product'
FROM `t1`
  LEFT JOIN `t3`
    ON `t1`.`id` = `t3`.`t1_id`
  LEFT JOIN `t2`
    ON `t2`.`id` = `t3`.`t2_id`
  GROUP BY `t1`.`id`
```

**Demo** @ [***MySQL 5.5.32 Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df3e6/34)

Comment: nice one, to bad you have to modify it for each new field in t2 but it will do thanks mate =)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could use a nested query, something like:

```
SELECT (SELECT `name` AS `value_type` from `t2` WHERE `value` = "product") FROM `t3`
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don' really follow your logic with that query, wouldn't I have to do one nested query for each post in t2 and if so, say I have 10 posts in t2 I would have to do 11 queries right?

Comment: Unfortunately, the restriction exists that the nested query is bound to return one row for the construct to work. The basic considerations of your endeavor were laid out in the comments, it is clear that it is hardly doable in one query. I provided this answer mainly to the `my wish is to use the name-field from t2 as column name for t3` statement as well as the title of the question.

Comment: in that case wouldn't it just be better to do 2 queries, one for the t1_ids with the limit and one for the test of the variables and then handle the rest after the result?